# C++ ¿Se puede definir una plantilla de clases con dos tipos genéricos?

Tags: c++

Tal cual definimos plantillas de Funciones con mas de dos tipos genéricos, intenté definir una clase genérica con dos tipos genéricos que podria tener como entrada en el constructor algo asi:

```
template <class T,class U>
class human{
    private:
        T saldo;
        U id;
    public:
        human(T Saldo, U ID){
            saldo=Saldo;
            id=ID;

        U getID();

        T getSaldo();        
    }
};
```

Aunque la clase carece de sentido practico quisiera saber si es posible... Y si la definición de los metodos seria de esta forma:

```
template <class T, class U>
T human<T,U>::getSaldo()
{
    return saldo;
}

template <class T, class U>
U human<T,U>::getID()
{
    return id;
}
```

De antemano, el compilador g++ da los siguientes errores:

**error:** `no declaration matches ‘T human<T, U>::getSaldo()’
 T human<T,U>::getSaldo()`

**error:** `no declaration matches ‘U human<T, U>::getID()’
 U human<T,U>::getID()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí se puede, tu código no compila porque declaraste dos funciones
(`getSaldo` y `getID`) dentro del constructor de `human`, y no dos
métodos dentro de la clase `human`.

La identación es engañosa, el cierre de llave debajo de `T getSaldo()` 
debería ir entre `id=ID;` y `U getID();`, así:

```
template <class T,class U>
class human{
    private:
        T saldo;
        U id;
    public:
        human(T Saldo, U ID){
            saldo=Saldo;
            id=ID;
        } // Va aquí

        U getID();

        T getSaldo();        
    // No va aquí
};
```